# Remove swap partition and extend root one(ext4)

Tags: debian, partition, swap, resize2fs

```
sda      8:0    0   400G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   953M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0   7.5G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 391.6G  0 part /
```

I'm having this type of partitioning where `sda2` is SWAP.

So I wish to  remove swap and resize the `sda5`

I have followed many guides(used search) here and also over some other website, but no luck, if i remove both of the partitions and create new one, the server is not loaded up back and i need to reinstall it fully.

Can't use gparted as I get an error(I'm not VPS and cant run GUI).

Seems my case is specific, so how should i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

First: *"I get an error"* –– would you tell us the error message?

Second: It seems that you use the Master Boot Record based partioning scheme and sda5 is a logical partition, but sda2 is a primary partition. So you have to resize the extended partition where sda5 is located. This is only  possible when `/` is not mounted, which means that you have to use a Live System like GRML, where you can use `gparted` anyway.